# OpenBSD and Dovecot, external mail client can't recive mail

Tags: email, imap, dovecot, openbsd

I have an OpenBSD serevr with OpenSMTPD and Dovecot, and I have a problem problem only with external mail clients. I can send mail but I can't receive mail from my IMAP/IMAPS server.

With mutt everything is ok. I don't understand what the problem is.

#### From Maillog

## In

```
Nov 11 19:12:18 server smtpd[413]: smtp-in: Accepted message a074c5e9 on session 43956de187d430c7: from=<xxxx@xxxxxx.xx>, to=<info@gianlucamuscelli.it>, size=7299, ndest=1, proto=ESMTP
Nov 11 19:12:18 server smtpd[413]: delivery: Ok for a074c5e9659948cd: from=<xxx@xxxxxx.xx>, to=<info@gianlucamuscelli.it>, user=info, method=maildir, delay=1s, stat=Delivered
```

## Out

```
Nov 11 19:11:38 server smtpd[413]: relay: Ok for f46bebb83463a4f7: session=43956ddf286b20f3, from=<info@gianlucamuscelli.it>, to=<xxxx@xxxxxx.xx>, rcpt=<->, source=192.168.1.30, relay=17.133.229.12 (mx6.mail.icloud.com), delay=4s, stat=250 2.5.0 Ok.
```

```
$ dovecot --version
2.2.15
$ dovecot -n 
# 2.2.15: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: OpenBSD 5.7 i386  ffs
auth_socket_path = /var/dovecot/auth-userdb
base_dir = /var/dovecot/
first_valid_uid = 1000
hostname = mail.gianlucamuscelli.it
imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail tb-extra-mailbox-sep tb-lsub-flags
listen = *
login_greeting = IMAP Server Ready.
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%u/Inbox
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
mmap_disable = yes
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = bsdauth
}
pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
postmaster_address = postmaster@gianlucamuscelli.it
protocols = imap pop3
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/mail.gianlucamuscelli.it.crt
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 4096
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/mail.gianlucamuscelli.it.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

$ netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10025        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.465       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.143                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.993                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.80        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.80        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.443       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.995                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.110                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.8025                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.25        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10027        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.8026         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.53           *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.443       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10028        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.25           *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.53        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.8952         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.25                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.10028              *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  fe80::1%lo0.10028      *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  fe80::1%lo0.25         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.8952               *.*                    LISTEN


$ ll /var/mail
total 8
drwx------  7 info  info   512 Nov  7 16:35 user
$ ll /var/mail/user
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 info  info  512 Nov  7 16:35 Drafts
drwx------  5 info  info  512 Nov  8 14:14 Inbox
drwxr-xr-x  5 info  info  512 Nov  7 16:35 Sent
drwxr-xr-x  5 info  info  512 Nov  7 16:35 Spam
drwxr-xr-x  5 info  info  512 Nov  7 16:35 Trash

$ netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10025        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.465       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.143                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.993                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.80        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.80        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.443       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.995                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.110                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.8025                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.25        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10027        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.8026         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.53           *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.443       *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.10028        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.25           *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  192.168.1.30.53        *.*                    LISTEN
tcp          0      0  127.0.0.1.8952         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.25                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.10028              *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  fe80::1%lo0.10028      *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  fe80::1%lo0.25         *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  ::1.8952               *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: What are your smtpd's settings? It's where delivery begins, after all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the error and I have solved alone...

```
$ sudo vi /etc/login.conf

dovecot:\
            :openfiles-cur=512:\
            :openfiles-max=2048:\
            :tc=daemon: 

$ sudo cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf 

$ sudo /etc/rc.d/dovecot stop
$ sudo /etc/rc.d/dovecot start
```

From /var/log/maillog

```
Nov 12 16:14:39 server dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.15 starting up for imap
Nov 12 16:14:53 server dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<info>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.1.1, lip=192.168.1.30, mpid=18612, TLS, session=<oEWnZ1kk8wDAqAEB>
```

Thank you...